# How to use two jquery library (1.4.2 & 1.6.2) simultaneously?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox, struts2-jquery

In a jsp page I am using two jQuery libraries (1.6.2 & 1.4.2), jquery-1.6.2.js for struts2-jquery-plugin and jQuery 1.4.2 for jQuery Lightbox. The problem is when I use both my light box it's not working and when I remove jquery-1.4.2.js then my other stuff is not working but lightbox is working fine. How to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download the <s>last version of [jQuery 1.9.1](http://jquery.com/download/)</s> [jQuery 1.8.3](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js)
2. Download the last version of [struts2-jquery](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/downloads/list)
3. Download the last version of [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Enjoy :).

Note : they should both work on the `jQuery 1.8.3 library` if they don't on the `1.9.1`, to download an old jquery library see [this link](http://jquery.com/download/).

Comment: latest version of struts2-jquery using jquery-1.8.3.js and latest version of lightbox is using jquery-1.7.3.js, so it might get conflict again, am i right?

Comment: @JeetuVerma Lightbox works with 1.8.3 see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/F3KBk/)

Comment: yes it is working with 1.8.3. thnx for this. can you give me link for any lightbox in that i can open my jsp page(this jsp page includes html code, a youtube video and images also).

Comment: I gave a link for lightbox2 for a lightbox with more features see [google](http://tinyurl.com/b2evugv).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official way if you aren't able to update the other dependent libraries:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="log">
  <h3>Before $.noConflict(true)</h3>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>

<script>
var $log = $( "#log" );

$log.append( "2nd loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery + "<br>" );

/*
Restore globally scoped jQuery variables to the first version loaded
(the newer version)
*/
jq162 = jQuery.noConflict(true);

$log.append( "<h3>After $.noConflict(true)</h3>" );
$log.append( "1st loaded jQuery version ($): " + $.fn.jquery + "<br>" );
$log.append( "2nd loaded jQuery version (jq162): " + jq162.fn.jquery + "<br>" );
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I used this solution but my lightbox code is not working and i am getting this output:Before $.noConflict(true)

2nd loaded jQuery version ($): 1.4.2
After $.noConflict(true)

1st loaded jQuery version ($): 1.6.4
2nd loaded jQuery version (jq162): 1.4.2

Comment: you need to replace the "$"s in the lightbox code to "jq162".

Comment: hey but lightbox code which i am using have 6 library so how to change in all 6 library.